# I am trying to write a JUnit test case for a method to insert timesheet which takes a parameter as employee Id. How should I try?

Tags: java, api, unit-testing, testing, junit

I tried to create a new object in timesheet type and assign values.But I have  a method call insertTimesheet which takes employeeId. As there is no such value for employeeId in timesheet object , the test gets fail.

```
@Test
public void testInsertTimesheet() {
    Timesheet expectedToSave = new Timesheet( 1001 ,"2019-01-10", "2019-01-05", "comment section is this ", "saved", null, null);  
    int actualInsertData = timesheetRepository.insertTimesheet(expectedToSave, 100789);
    Assertions.assertEquals(expectedToSave, actualInsertData);
}
```

Comment: What is the value returning from insertTimeSheet() method ? is it saved timesheet id?

Comment: @Vimukthi_R The insert method will return INT if the data is saved successfully i.e 1.

Comment: Is it a random integer value? what will return if not saved successfully?

Comment: assertEquals will check if two values are equal. If yes test passes else test fails. You need to compare the value returned with the success case value from your method.

Comment: @Vimukthi_R it will return 0 if it is not saved successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JdbcTemplate.update()` method will return number of rows effected. if not inserted successfully it will throw `DataAccessException` exception.

```
@Test
public void testInsertTimesheet() {
    Timesheet expectedToSave = new Timesheet( 1001 ,"2019-01-10", "2019-01-05", "comment section is this ", "saved", null, null);  
    int actualInsertData = timesheetRepository.insertTimesheet(expectedToSave, 100789); //In here number of effected rows is 1 so insertTimeSheet() will return 1
    Assert.assertEquals(1, actualInsertData); //expected value is 1
}
```

Comment: I tried this way but its showing java.lang.NullPointerException @Vimukthi_R

Comment: add TimeSheet constructor method. issue is in your insertTimesheet() method. You are trying to get null value from passed timeSheet object

Comment: I have  already created constructor method in timesheet.Can you please give me example.

Comment: `new Timesheet( 1001 ,"2019-01-10", "2019-01-05", "comment section is this ", "saved", null, null)` In here what are these null values ?

Comment: whenever a new timesheet is added the status will be "SAVED" and approve date & approve by value will be null. That's the approve date & by value.

Comment: can you find the line where exception is throwing using debugging ?

Comment: its the same line '''jdbcTemplate.update(Queries.INSERT_TIMESHEET,param)'''. As it returns int value. But as above the actualInsertData value should be 1. Isn't it ?

Comment: Yes if saved successfully it should return a positive integer. In this case 1. cannot find where it is throwing null pointer exception.

Comment: It was annotation issue.I was using JunitPlatform annotation instead of using SpringBootTest annotation because I was trying to test the repository class.